# CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly and Dependency Properties

Tags: c#, xaml, dependency-properties, fxcop

I currently have a Dependency Property as such:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyPropertyDefaults", typeof(ICollection<string>), typeof(MyPanel), new PropertyMetadata(new List<string>()));

public ICollection<string> MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return GetValue(MyPropertyProperty) as ICollection<string>;
    }

    set
    {
        this.SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value);
    }
}
```

The aim is that this subpanel will be passed a list via a binding, that the subpanel manipulates, and then the parent can read later. E.g.

```
 <xaml:MyPanel MyProperty="{Binding MyPropertyList}" />
```

However, FxCop reports CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly and I need to remove the setter, which is required by the property. How do I fix this? What is the correct way to do what I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Declare the setter as private like this:

```
public class MyPanel : Panel
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyPropertyDefaults", typeof(ICollection<string>), typeof(MyPanel), new PropertyMetadata(new List<string>()));

    public ICollection<string> MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(MyPropertyProperty) as ICollection<string>;
        }

        private set
        {
            this.SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not possible? The property 'MyPanel.MyProperty' cannot be set because it does not have an accessible set accessor.

Comment: No, the interface needs the setter to be public in order to use it. I suspect the problem lies in the collection I'm using and I shouldn't be passing collections directly as I am, but some other way?